# Gensim Word2Vec object has no attribute vector_size when loading file

Tags: python-3.x, word2vec, gensim

I'm trying to load an already trained word2vec model downloaded from [here](http://hlt.isti.cnr.it/wordembeddings/) by using the following code, as suggested by the aforementioned website:

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
model=Word2Vec.load('wiki_iter=5_algorithm=skipgram_window=10_size=300_neg-samples=10.m')
```

When I try to execute that code, I get the following error:

```
UserWarning: detected Windows; aliasing chunkize to chunkize_serial
warnings.warn("detected Windows; aliasing chunkize to chunkize_serial")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\DavideV\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\tesi\tesi\tesi.py", line 112, in <module>
model=Word2Vec.load('wiki_iter=5_algorithm=skipgram_window=10_size=300_neg-samples=10.m')
File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\word2vec.py", line 979, in load
return load_old_word2vec(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\deprecated\word2vec.py", line 155, in load_old_word2vec
'size': old_model.vector_size,
AttributeError: 'Word2Vec' object has no attribute 'vector_size'
```

I suppose that this is due to the fact that the model has probably been trained with a previous version of gensim, but I would prefer to avoid to retrain it.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Which version of gensim was it saved from, and into which version are you loading it? Gensim tries to retain the ability to load older models in official releases, and will fix bugs where old models don't load – so just making sure your problem is reported, or trying the very latest release, might make the old model loadable again.

Comment: I don't know the version used to train the model. Mine is 3.4.0. If I don't solve the problem in the meantime, I will try to open a ticket on github.

Comment: If you don't need the latest gensim, rolling back a version or two might also be a sufficient workaround.